# Admob : Ad serving is limited - The number of ads you can show has been limited. For details, go to the Policy center

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, expo, admob

I'm new to admob. I published my first android app (written in expo react-native). I followed the instructions https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/admob/ on including admob ads in my app. But after sometime of including the ad Ids for Banner Ad, Interstitial Ad and Reward Ad I get this message "**Ad serving is limited The number of ads you can show has been limited. For details, go to the Policy center**" in my admob account.

It says "Invalid traffic concerns". I followed the below links but it didn't help me resolve it

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3342099?hl=en
https://oko.uk/blog/ad-serving-has-been-limited

[image]

[image]

**Resolutions I followed but none of these helped**

1. Removed all 3 ads i,e, Banner Ad, Interstitial Ad and Reward Ad. After waiting for couple of days (5 days or so) this message was removed. After one day I again created these ads and implemented their Ids in my app and released it on Google Play Store. Ads did not show in my app but still, after 2 days I again got this "invalid traffic concerns" message on my account.
2. Implemented frequency capping for the ads but that didn't help. Ads are not showing on my app yet.
3. I've implemented ads.txt properly.
4. I've added the payment details on the account.
5. Implemented the test ad Ids and they worked. But when replaced with real Ad Ids they don't work.

None of these helped me. Please let me know how to proceed on this.

By the way, this is my app - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.starcoding.matchmeifucan_cow_bull

Thanks.

Comment: i have checked your app now admob ad showing. i am facing same issue(ad serve limit), can you please me or guide me how to resolve this

Comment: Hi Binesh, I just posted an answer. Hope that helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @SandeepAmarnath I downloaded your app now and found ads. Could you please tell me the solution that you made to solve ad serving limit issue

Comment: @AbanoubIstfanous, please find my answer below. These are the steps I took to solve my issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I installed your app but I cannot see any ads because the ads limitation, so here some general advice about AdMob Ads to avoid limiting your ad serving:

1. avoid clicking on your own ads, and tell your friends and family not to click on the ads (this is very important)
2. if your app have very small traffic, consider removing ads until you have decent number of active users so no small group of people could affect your ads then activate ads
3. make sure that you are pre loading interstitial ads before showing them
4. if you are using interstitial ad when users open the app, consider using App Open Ads
5. make sure that banner ads does not obscure any content of your app (to avoid accidental clicks)
6. when you want to make cab limit, make it 1 ad every 10 minutes for example, always make the first value 1 ad per a period of time, to avoid repeating ads.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think I need to remove the ads until my app gets active users like you said. Will follow that and see.

Answer (score 6):

**My issue got resolved now so I'm posting an answer to my question about the steps I took**

I actually put a limit on the ads to be shown and then waited for more than a month (the most important step where you should not open your app many times if there are not many downloads yet).

The rule is simple. Let's say there are only 4 people who downloaded the game and they always open the game to see the ad, then the number of ads shown will be more but the app itself has fewer downloads. In this case, Google will put the limit as it thinks the people are using the app just to increase ad count and make money.

So what should you do?

Follow these steps and hopefully, you will see the ads soon.

1. Make sure your ads are set up correctly. You can check this by replacing your ads with test ads while developing the game and see if the test ads show up in the simulator or your test device. If this works while building the game, replace the test ad IDs with actual ad IDs (Note: Never leave the main ads in the development. Always use test ads and then while building the game, you replace the test ad with the main ad)
2. As I said in the first line, put a limit to the ads. I mean Frequency capping (pink outlined box below). You can put any number but I chose to show no more than 1 ad every 30 minutes. (Don't worry, this will just be temporary and once google believes that this app is gaining popularity, then even though this limit exists they show more ads than this limit you've placed)

   This step is for Interstitial Ads and Reward Ads. This doesn't apply to Banner Ad.

[image: Frequency capping]

3. Once you follow these two steps, the difficult step now is to JUST WAIT :). This seems silly but that's true and I can say this from personal experience. By Wait, I mean don't open your app too often in the initial days. Maybe 3 or 4 days once, just open it for no more than 2 or 3 times. This lets Google think that you're not trying to generate false revenue. Focus more on getting more downloads. Do Google Campaign so that your ads will show up as an ad to multiple people who use other apps. Even I'm new to this step and I haven't yet done a campaign (planning to do it soon). https://ads.google.com/intl/en_ca/home/

The above steps are what I did (except campaign) for my ads to show up again after a month.

Comment: i followed same but not again ad limit placed, daily my app is downloading 2000+

Comment: Capping makes sense for the interstitial ads but I am not sure how is this solution applicable for rewarded video ads as their sole purpose is to reward a user for seeing an ad. User opts for it.

Answer (score 5):

In my case when the click rate reached 5%, the ad service limit started.
There is no way to prevent users to click on ads.
Also, there is no way to know when this will be resumed to get ad impressions.
Normally the limit alert will be gone in a week, but it will appear again if you try to use AdMob again in the Mediation setting.
Maybe you need to wait a long time, one month or 2 months, no one knows.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Based on my experience

1. Just adjust your native ads layout from invalid clicks.
2. Don't open your own app in your phone.
3. Don't click your own app ads.
4. Add your phone as test device in AdMob.
5. Try to start campaign on your app like
   Europe side traffic and wait for sometimes I am not giving exact
   time but in less than a month it will work if your ad don't have
   invalid clicks.

Answer (score 3):

What ever you do Google Admob has strange policy for app developers for showing ads in their apps.

1. Policy One: App should be uploaded on multiple app store.
2. Policy Two: Once ads limit placed it will be revised after one year.
3. Policy Three: If you account is created from a from low revenue country more chance of ad serving Limit put on you.

Answer (score 0):

what is the advantage of removing all ad ids from app and then upload ur app again????
ok u have removed all ads and ad limit issue is resolved then what then if u put ad ids again the limit will come again so thats not the solution i have tried much i have an answer follow these steps.
1- if ur admob is not verified with pin then limit ur ads like
use one native and one interstital ad for now on then slowly slowly increase the number of time with the time users increasing and
2- adjust your native ads layout from invalid clicks.
3- Don't open your own app in your phone.
4- Don't click your own app ads.
5- Add your phone as test device in AdMob.
6- Try to start campaign on your app like Europe side traffic and wait for sometimes I am not giving exact time but in less than a month it will work if your ad don't have invalid clicks.

Answer (score 0):

I was experimenting with a few things after the limit was placed on my account. I have a fairly new app that currently has ~4k DAU.

It looks like when there is an abnormal number of `Ad requests` when compared to your DAU, Google puts this limit. From the attached graphs, it's clearly visible that `Ad Requests` and `Match rate` has an inverse relationship with each other.

[image]

You can try limiting the ad requests and see if it works for you. I put limits on my banners via code and control it from Firebase Remote config, and have interstitial limits set from AdMob console.